# GridList Animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I have a horizontal scrollview gridlist. I am implementing animation on the grid items inside the grid list.

1. The hovered item's dimensions(height and width) should increase and the previous and next sibling should shift accordingly so that currently hovered item should not overlap/cover the previous and next sibling.
2. Dimensions of the adjacent siblings/griditem(previous and next) should also increase but lesser than the current sibling or hovered item.
3. Lets say there is an infinite horizontal gridlist. If i hover on 3rd griditem, its height will increase from 100px to 200px and similarly width from 100px to 200px. Left and right griditem(2nd and 4th) to this should shift accordingly so that they do not get covered due to the increase in the dimensions of the currently hovered griditem. And, the dimensions of left and right griditem should increase to 50px.
4. I have added the sample code. In this, opacity is changing instead of dimensions. If I put transforms for dimensions, it disturbs the alignment.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.dimensions').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    event.target.classList.add('primary');
    let prev = event.target.previousElementSibling;
    if (prev) {
     prev.classList.add('secondary');
    }
    let next = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    if (next) {
     next.classList.add('secondary');
    }
  })
  
  item.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
    event.target.classList.remove('primary');
    let prev = event.target.previousElementSibling;
    if (prev) {
     prev.classList.remove('secondary');
    }
    let next = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    if (next) {
     next.classList.remove('secondary');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.parent {
  margin-top:100px;
}

.dimensions {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.dimensions.secondary  {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: .9;
}

.dimensions.primary {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity:1;
}

.dimensions {
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body class="flex parent">
      <div class="dimensions"></div>
      <div class="dimensions"></div>
      <div class="dimensions"></div>
      <div class="dimensions"></div>
      <div class="dimensions"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add some code, looks like a homework question

Comment: Sample Code added for reference

Comment: I think its working as expected, regarding the opacity, you added opacity to .9 on secondary class. what really do you expect ??

Comment: So, this is working fine. In place of opacity I want to change the dimensions. Like, image should be enlarged on hover. I am trying to implement a gallery kind of horizontal infinite scroll

Comment: you could use slick slider, which is better for your need

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion. It will solve the horizontal scroll part though I did it. But still the onhover dimension change animation is what is bugging me